# Angular 8 Polling Using Observables

Tags: angular

Hey i am upgrading my Project from angular 5 to angular 8. This is the code i was using for polling.

```
 Observable.interval(this.intervalTime).timeout(600000)
                .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
                .subscribe(i => {
                    this.timeOutValue++;
                    //fun();
                });
```

fun() is setting alive as true or false. But now in angular 8 interval is not defined. Will someone please help me for workaround.

Comment: have you tried to install rxjs-compat ?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs5-6? There's also guidance via https://update.angular.io/.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `interval` function from 'rxjs' and perform your operations in a pipe.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { timeout, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

class MyClass {
  private intervalTime: number;
  private alive: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  private timeOutValue = 0;

  myPollingMethod() {
    interval(this.intervalTime).pipe(
      timeout(600000),
      takeWhile(() => this.alive)
    ).subscribe(i => {
      this.timeOutValue++;
      //fun();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a throttle time for continuous polling or debounce

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).throttleTime(2000).subscribe(x => console.log())
const interval$ = interval(1000);
const debouncedInterval = interval$.pipe(debounce(val => timer(val * 200)));
const subscribe = debouncedInterval.subscribe(val =>
console.log(`Example Two: ${val}`)
);
```